# How to get text input from user in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

How to make pygame print input from user:

I am trying to have the user type something and pygame prints it on the screen.

This is my current program:

```
import pygame, pygame.font, pygame.event, pygame.draw, string
from pygame.locals import *

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
  pygame.font.init()
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return string.join(current_string,"")

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
    print ask(screen, "Name") + " was entered"

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I want it so when the user hits enter, it emptys the screen.

Help Me!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example script that blits input to the screen.  It shows how you can modify a `name` string while looping through the pygame event queue.  Each frame, the screen is cleared and the name surface is rebuilt and blit.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def name():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 360))
    name = ""
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
    while True:
        for evt in pygame.event.get():
            if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evt.unicode.isalpha():
                    name += evt.unicode
                elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    name = name[:-1]
                elif evt.key == K_RETURN:
                    name = ""
            elif evt.type == QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        block = font.render(name, True, (255, 255, 255))
        rect = block.get_rect()
        rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
        screen.blit(block, rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name()
    pygame.quit()
```

Here is a [gist version](https://gist.github.com/4428513)

Comment: Can you make it so the input is shown in a box titled "Name"?

Comment: I'd rather you try it yourself first.  There's enough in this example to show you how to blit a `Font.render` surface with "Name" in it above the input.  If you have any questions, I'm glad to answer them.

Comment: A user has been editing the script in this post because they receive an error on exit.  I'm wondering if the error is the same [mentioned in the pygame wiki](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#In%20IDLE%20why%20does%20the%20Pygame%20window%20not%20close%20correctly?).  Please try the updated version and comment if it doesn't work so we can figure out what the issue is.